# wireless issues asus x550lc

Tags: wireless, internet, asus, iwlwifi

i am facing a lot of problems when i try to connect to internet over wifi in my asus x550lc laptop. In windows 8 the wifi works perfectly fine and its fast and stable.
but when i use Ubuntu 14.04 ( i tried ubuntu 14.10 live booting also.. same problems), i found these issues
-> Unstable wifi connection. The connection goes off if i use it for 5-10 minutes. in the middle of downloads etc
-> Very slow internet & weak signal 
-> Wi-Fi password prompts appear on login screen.

i tried several solution found in online, like
-> switch off the power management by Ubuntu for your wireless device
->  resolve  bug in the Debian Avahi daemon in Ubuntu

but the problem still exists. any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I know what the problem is.  You see, when you installed Ubuntu, you almost certainly depended on that wireless connection for the internet access Ubuntu needs to install properly.  It probably worked just well enough to try and fail.  Fortunately you probably don't have to re-install.  You simply need to connect internet to it via an Ethernet cable and then attempt to update your computer.  When you open the system update screen, be sure to press CHECK to make sure it compares and updates.

If that doesn't fix your problem, please re-install Ubuntu but only with a wired connection.  I suspect it will download the correct drivers automatically and then the WiFi will work properly after that.